# Scheduler still executing

Tags: java

So my team and I are experiencing an issue where we believe that the scheduler is not disposing properly. We have this piece of code here which cancels a ScheduleFuture, and then creates a new one.

```
    public void restartEventTimer(long time) {
    try {
        if (disposed) {
            return;
        }
        timeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
        eventTime = time;
        if (timeout != null) {
            timeout.cancel(false);
        }
        timeout = null;
        final int timesend = (int) time / 1000;

        for (MapleCharacter chr : getPlayers()) {
            chr.getClient().getSession().write(MaplePacketCreator.getClock(timesend));
        }
        timeOut(time);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogHelper.INVOCABLE.get().info("restartEventTimer: Event name " + em.getName() + ", Instance name : " + name + " ", ex);
    }
}
```

Now it comes to my understanding that cancel does not dispose of the timer, instead it sets a value in the backend which isDone() gets set to true. I was wondering if it is because the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor just hasn't run through the code which handles pruning it in the backend. Should I create a wrapper for ScheduleFuture and override the default implementation to make sure if isDone() is called that it wont run through the Runnable.

```
    public boolean timeOut(final long delay) {
    if (disposed || em == null) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        timeout = TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(() -> {
            if (disposed || em == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                em.getIv().invokeFunction("scheduledTimeOut", this);
            } catch (Exception e) { //i know, it should be just NoSuchMethodException, but idc.
                 LogHelper.INVOCABLE.get().info("timeOut: Event name " + em.getName() + ", Instance name : " + name + " " + e);
            }
        }, delay);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Null pointer arises when you dispose in the scheduledTimeOut method, thus making this particular event instance object null and making timeout throw a nullpointer
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogHelper.INVOCABLE.get().info("timeOut: Event name " + em.getName() + ", Instance name : " + name + " " + e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

We also made sure we set these parameters to the executor:

```
    setContinueExistingPeriodicTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
    setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
    setKeepAliveTime(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: `} catch (NullPointerException e) {` -- you shouldn't be catching this but rather preventing it. I suggest that you get rid of that catch block

Comment: That catch block is for the external scripts. Yes in an perfect world we should be preventing it, but we did not write a lot of those scripts. So we have that in place for now. But my main concern is regarding the scheduler.